# Why does Kivy not allow multiplication between NumericProperties?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and trying to get my head around how to use NumericProperties.
I have the following code:

```
from random import randint
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
import numpy as np

class Player(Widget):
    speed = NumericProperty(10)
    angle = randint(0, 360)
    direction_x = NumericProperty(np.cos(angle))
    direction_y = NumericProperty(np.sin(angle))
    direction = ReferenceListProperty(direction_x, direction_y)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(direction_x * speed, direction_y * speed)
    
class Game(App):
    def build(self):
        return Player()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Kivy seems to be having trouble in multiplying the NumericProperties speed and direction_x/y. I was wondering a) why that is and b) how I can get around doing these sort of calculations in kivy more generally. I will also note that `velocity = direction * speed` was equally unsuccessful, and I did not have much success using vectors either.

Comment: NumericProperty is a class, which is why you are unable to perform calculation with it. You can check out the property definitions in the [source file](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/ca1b918c656f23e401707388f25f4a63d9b8ae7d/kivy/properties.pyx#L628)

Comment: You can accomplish the equivalent by defining `velocity` as a `ListProperty`, and using `on_speed()` and `on_direction()` methods to set its values.